# How to globally disable/hide/replace a component by name in React?

Tags: reactjs, featuretoggle

I have a large React app and I have a few components that I would like to completely disable from a config or global level. Is there any kind of global hook that I can use that is called before any component is rendered? If so, I imagine I can check the name of the component and return `null` if the name is on the disabled list. How would you do this?

Comment: If you have a global state store like redux, you can store a flag in the state, then just disable the component based on that property in the component class.

Comment: ... redux or context (or even window.varFlag) ... and you don't have to return `<div />` - rendering null to virtual DOM removes entirely component from real DOM

Comment: Can you use the state?  i.e. `<Component style={'display':this.enabled ? true: false} />` and then just enabled/disable by updating its state in its calling parent record, like `compref.setState({'enabled':true/false})`?  Worried about missing your intent here.

Comment: @Byron edit question text/title - add 'feature flag'?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger it wouldn't be 'global config driven' and not 'completely disable' - not hide it by css, don't render it rather. It's enough to not render children. Using refs would be an overkill for that (+ modifying 'body' of hidden component), managing them globally? Parent != global. Global & connected parent ? then passing prop would be enough (probably one time change - not dynamic), no need for refs.... ect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this:

[React's Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) allows you pass props through every level of the component tree so you can use them as flags to enable/disable components. Should be used sparingly however.

[Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) are basically just functions that return a component. You could wrap your components in logic to render them as needed.

Or of course you could use a global state manager like redux to set global states.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, so, I'll just describe one simple way: using references and updating the states accordingly.

Full working feature hide/showing sandbox online: [codesandbox.io ReactJS Feature Hide/Show Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/r734rl7o4o)

Defined are two classes, `class Feature extends React.Component` and `class App extends React.Component`.  The `render()` for `<Feature/>` is...

```
  render() {
    if (!this.state.enabled) {
      return <div />;
    }
    return (
      <div className="Feature">
        <h1>My Feature!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And the option for enabling/disabling a feature in `<App />` would handle display/hiding like so...

```
  handleOnClick(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.feature.setState({ enabled: true });
    } else {
      this.feature.setState({ enabled: false });
    }
  }
```

Of course, you need to make sure that `<Feature />` has the reference set...

```
    <Feature
      ref={instance => {
        this.feature = instance;
      }}
    />
```

Comment: and make it global for component placed deeper in structure .... ? it's definitively not a question about hidding direct child

Comment: This solution could work, but as I mentioned, I have a very large code base. I need a solution that is more at the framework-level.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need **simplest solution** just use browser global vars and check it in render.

   `render() {
      if( window.globalFlag ) return null
      return (
        <div> feature content...`

   Drawbacks:

   - modifying component,
   - using global scope,
   - **some unnecessary code can be run earlier** (f.e. `constructor`) **and later** (f.e. `componentDidMount`).
2. **Use HOCs** - wrap your component - connecting with global store using redux or context API.

   `<FlagsProvider store={flagStore}>
      <SomeComponent_1>
        <SomeComponent_2>
          <FlagsConsumer flag="someFeatureFlag">
            <SomeFeatureComponent />`

   `<FlagsConsumer/>` connects to store (redux connect would be an inner wrapper - composing HOCs) and conditionally renders `<SomeFeatureComponent />` (or null).

   Of course HOC can pass received props to wrapped component - it can be functionally transparent.
3. **Don't reinvent the wheel** - use some ready [module](https://github.com/garbles/flag), read tutorials, google for sth suitable.

**HOC can also play a role of A/B testing.**

Comment: I have a large code base. Going to each component and adding a HOC or a flag inside the component will be a LOT of work. Is there not some framework-level hook before any component is rendered?

Comment: It would hurt performance. Do you really need it for each component? Extend `React.Component` and use it as own base class (search & replace)? It would be removable feature for 'final deployment'.